# Ideas for good class name

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions, framework-design

How would you name a class with the following public interface:

```
/// <summary>
///     Enqeues and exectutes actions synchronously on seperated threads using the <see cref="ThreadPool"/>. 
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
///     Syncronism is guaranteed on a per-instance base in that each enqued action will be executed
///     after the previous action has completed execution for each instance of <see cref="ThreadPoolExectutor" /> 
/// </remarks>
internal class ThreadPoolExectutor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ThreadPoolExectutor"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="capacity">The absolute (not the initial) number of elements that the <see cref="ThreadPoolExectutor"/> can contain.</param>
    public ThreadPoolExectutor(int capacity)

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when exception occured during execution.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ExceptionEventArgs> ExceptionOccurred;

    /// <summary>
    /// Enqueues a new action with a single parameter for execution on the thread pool.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">
    /// The action to enqueue for execution.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="param">
    /// The parameter for the action.
    /// </param>
    /// <typeparam name="TArg">
    /// The type of the <paramref name="param"/>.
    /// </typeparam>
    public void Execute<TArg>(Action<TArg> action, TArg param)

    /// <summary>
    /// Enqueues a new action with no parameters for execution on the thread pool.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">
    /// The action to enqueue for execution.
    /// </param>
    public void Execute(Action action)
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two variants of Execute(Action<T>, T)? You can use lambda expressions to close over any arguments. This class also looks a lot like a System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.

Comment: "Enqeues and exectutes"  "Manages queue and executes" perhaps :)

Comment: I was going to suggest `SerialTaskDispatcher` as an answer, but @Strilanc's mention of a class with similar-sounding functionality looks like it might be a better alternative.

Comment: Naming is just about the hardest part of programming: there is often no single right answer.

Comment: @shambulator System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler is actually abstract. Still have to implement the 'run on thread pool' stuff. Actually, tasks run on the thread pool by default I think.

Comment: @Strilanc I want to be able to do `this.executor.Execute(this.OnStart, itemToStart)` in a typesafe way.

Comment: @Strilanc IMHO TaskScheduler executes all Queued tasks asynchronously. I want each Task to be executed one after the other. (On a different thread that the caller though).

Comment: @bitbonk I didn't mean you should use Object, I meant the function shouldn't be there at all [because you can just use Execute(() => OnStart(itemToStart))]. Also, TaskScheduler can execute calls synchronously. In fact, I wrote and use one which runs calls on the thread pool one after another.

Comment: +1 for clarification on the TaskScheduler. Also I understood that you didn't mean to say that I should use Object. `Execute(() => OnStart(itemToStart))` IMHO adds some useless noise `() => ` additionally the user might get the closure issues when passing parameters your way wich I wanted to avoid. Additionally and that is the most important part: I also want to support .NET 2.0 and still be typesafe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Enqeues and exectutes actions

I would call it `ThreadPoolDispatcher`

Comment: I was going to say something similar, but the name should indicate that there is a queuing mechanism at work so your Thread won't be dispatched immediately.

Comment: Well better than a "tutor" since I see no tutorial in the class, and it does not seem to be an "Exec" to nor does it "Execute" anyone :)

Comment: @Justin Niessner  i disagree. queuing is internals of class and should not be exposed. i think Dispatcher is descriptive enough, it means that it *handles* threads the way it thinks it is best.

Comment: I renamed it to `ThreadPoolDispatcher` and remaned the `Execute` methods to `Invoke`. This matches `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher`.

Answer (score 1):

personally id try and refactor the class into 2 smaller ones to follow the Single Responsibility Principal - therefore have a class for Executing actions

ThreadPoolDispatcher [as per the above suggestion that i agree with]

and then a `ThreadPoolQueuer`  which will be responsible for queuing threads

just personal preference though

Comment: Going with YAGNI, I will refactor it your way as soon as I need seprate queueing strategies. (I wonder if this way of thinking is wise though).

Answer (score 0):

How about `ThreadPoolAgent`.

Answer (score -2):

I would name it `ThreadPoolManager`

Comment: manager is a bad name - it seems to indicate a God class and good design principles tell us to move away from those type of classes

Comment: I want all my classes to be God like and inspire awe in the beer holder :)